# Graphics and sound problems with Silent Hill: Shattered Memories on PCSX2?

Tags: pcsx2, silent-hill-shattered-memories

I have some problems with my *Silent Hill: Shattered Memories* via PCSX2 Emulator.

- First problem is the audio in some cutscenes is missing or is choppy. And also some sequences in cutscenes have very low FPS.
- Second one is that I have problem with my in game flashlight whose light cone is acting weird. As you can see in picture below it is have weird shaped objects in cone of Henry´s flashlight

[image: weird shadow in light cone of Henry´s flashlight]

How can I resolve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was solved by editing PCSX2 settings as follows

- **Config -> Video(GS) -> Plugin Settings**

[image: GSdx Settings]

```
    **Changes:**
    
             1. Render: -> Direct3D 11 (Software)
             2. Adapter -> *Your graphics card* (mine is on picture below)
             3. Interlacing -> Automatic(Default)
             4. Texture filternig -> Bilinear(PS2)?optional??
            
              -------------HARDWARE RENDERER SETTINGS-----------------------------
             5.  **Uncheck** Allow 
        
         - Allow 8-bit Textures
         - Large Framebuffer
         - enable HW Hacks
        
        
            
            ---------------SOFTWARE RENDERER SETTINGS-----------------------------
            
             6. **Check** 
    
     - Auto Flush
     - Mipmapping
     
    
     

 7. set Render Threads to 4

            
 8. Uncheck Edge Anti-alising(Del)
```

**But better option would be to install latest PCSX2 version 1.7.**

Comment: Perhaps list what you changed as well?

Comment: @TimmyJim Here you are, I edited it i think this is finest options(at least for me) but when you find something better let me know, it is know in general that SH: Shattered memories isn't optimalized very well ;)

Comment: @TimmyJim But better option would be to ```install latest PCSX2 version 1.7.```